# how to use hibernateTemplate to get EntityObject for multiple HQL

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have a table say

```
MyTable (myId,myStringCol1,myStringCol2,myStringCol3)
```

When Using

### QUERY1

```
hibernateTemplate.find("SELECT new(myId,myStringCol1) from MyTable")
```

I am getting the MyTable Object and for this there should be one constructor in the MyTable class like this

```
MyTable{
      MyTable(Integer id,String col1){
          this.id = id;
          this.col1 = col1;
       }

}
```

But when in another method I am calling like this

### QUERY2

```
hibernateTemplate.find("SELECT new(myId,myStringCol2) from MyTable")  ///myStringCol2
```

Here, there also be one constructor, like above, but we can't create the same signature constructor.
So when running the second query (QUERY2) I am getting the myStringCol2 values in col1 
because of the first constructor.

So how can I solve this problem..

Waiting for the suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
class MyTable1{
      MyTable1(Integer id,String col1, String col2){
          this.id = id;
          this.col1 = col1;
          this.col2 = col2;
       }

}
```

And then:

Q1

```
hibernateTemplate.find("SELECT new(myId,myStringCol1,'') from MyTable")
```

Q2

```
hibernateTemplate.find("SELECT new(myId,'',myStringCol2) from MyTable")
```

Would be nice **if** you could pass null instead of '', but AFAIK you **can not**, because there is a bug that prevents you from doing that: https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=985612&start=0. So, you will **have** to use **''**

Another option, inspired by Talha answer would be:

```
class MyTable{
      MyTable(Integer id,String col1, Boolean isColumn2){
          this.id = id;
          if(isColumn2){
             this.col2 = col2;
          }
          else{
             this.col1 = col1;
          }
      }      
}
```

Then you can just write:

Q1

```
hibernateTemplate.find("SELECT new(myId,myStringCol1,false) from MyTable")
```

Q2

```
hibernateTemplate.find("SELECT new(myId,myStringCol2,true) from MyTable")
```

Comment: I already tried with null, and I am not able to pass null in the place of the column.

Comment: Which is why I am suggesting you to use '', do not use null.-.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I would probably simply select the complete entity in both cases, because it wouldn't make much difference in terms of performance, you would have an attached entity, and it would be much simpler.

Now to answer your technical question, simply implement the loop over the results yourself:

```
String hql = "select mt.myId, mt.myStringCol2 from MyTable mt";
List<Object[]> rows = session.createQuery(hql).list();
List<MyTableDTO> result = new ArrayList<MyTableDTO>(rows.size());
for (Object[] row : rows) {
    result.add(new MyTableDTO((Long) row[0], (String) row[1]));
}
```

As simple as that, and you would have refactorable code as an additonal bonus.

I would also strongly advise against using the entity class to store the results of such queries. Create a specific DTO object containing only the fields returned by the query. If a method returns instances of an entity class, the caller will expect to get properly, fully populated, attached entity instances.

Comment: It would be very painful to create multiple DTO's
Because My table Has lots of columns and if I want to select different column in different methods. I just asked this as a sample questions.

Comment: And have you measured that it caused a significant performance problem to select the complete entity rather than selecting only some fields?

Answer (score 0):

What you need is a separate DTO.

```
MyTableDto {
      MyTableDto1(Integer id,String col) {
          this.id = id;
          this.col = col;
       }

}
```

You can then query the columns separately as:

```
hibernateTemplate.find("SELECT new MyTableDto(t.id,t.myStringCol1) from MyTable t");
```

and

```
hibernateTemplate.find("SELECT new MyTableDto(t.id,t.myStringCol2) from MyTable t");
```

To further remove ambiguity from your code and make it a bit more readable, you can create two separate DTO objects (they would only differ in their name, but would make your code more readable as they hold different data).